# WPF disable save button

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a save button that I want to disable if my validation fails.

My validation logic:

```
 public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnName)) return string.Empty;
            if (columnName.Equals("PostNr"))
            {
                if (!IsUdenlandskAdresse)
                {
                    bool erFireCifre = Regex.IsMatch(PostNr, "[0-9]{4}");
                    bool erGyldigtPostNr = PostNrBy.ContainsKey(PostNr);

                    if (!(erFireCifre && erGyldigtPostNr))
                    {
                        IsValid = false;
                        return "Ugyldigt postnummer";
                    }
                }

                if(IsUdenlandskAdresse && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PostNr))
                {
                    IsValid = false;
                    return "Postnummer skal oplyses";
                }


                IsValid = true;
                return null
            }
    }
```

My button:

```
<Button Margin="4" Content="Gem" Command="{Binding RetAdresseCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=RetAdresse}"/>
```

How would i go about doing this?

Comment: implement `CanExecute` in RetAdresseCommand properly: it shoul return flase if validation fails

Comment: How can i in my code check whether the validation was succesful or not?

Comment: an easy way to do that is: Create a bool property which store the result of validation (this property of course must use OnPropertyChanged event) and bind IsEnabled property of your button to this bool

Comment: I tried doing that, but I couldn't figure out how to set the boolean to false when validation failed and vice versa.

Comment: when " return "Ugyldigt postnummer";" means the validation is failed (at least if i get what you are saying in your language). Before the return just set your property to false. Else you set it to true

Comment: Ok i tried doing it (as you can see in my edit) I added a property IsValid and have bound IsEnabled to it. For some reason only one of my validations has to be succesful in order for IsValid to be set to true. Any idea why?

Comment: First of all, set IsValid to false by default. Secondly put a breakpoint in your method and a watch on IsValid variable and check how and when it is setted to True

Comment: if (!(erFireCifre && erGyldigtPostNr)) probably you need an OR( || ) here . You want both validation to be true right? i would write it if(erFireCifre == false || erGyldigtPostNr == false)

Comment: Did you get an answer?